# Custom template file for specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-community

I created custom attribute for category. How can I override default category template based on this custom attribute using observer?
What event should I look into?

Answer (score 0):

May be `catalog_category_prepare_save` event is work for you.

you can also find from [here](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default category template by using your project theme and load 
your category by custom attribute by observer by below given code :

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$collection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->loadByAttribute('custom_attribute_code', $custom_attribute_value);
```